# How to set default value in Dataset parsed from Dataframe if column is missing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a DataSet from the Dataframe using a case class.

```
case class test (language:String, users_count: String = "100")

+--------+-----------+
|language|users_count|
+--------+-----------+
|    Java|      20000|
|  Python|     100000|
|   Scala|       3000|
+--------+-----------+

df.as[test]
```

How to handle the scenario where a column is missing in the dataframe ?
The expectation is dataset populates default value provided in the case class.

If the dataframe only has one column, it throws an exception

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`users_count`' given input columns: [language];

Expected Result:

```
+--------+
|language|
+--------+
|    Java|      
|  Python|     
|   Scala| 
+--------+

df.as[test].collect(0)
test('Java',100) // where 100 is the default value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `map` function and explicitly call the constructor like this:

```scala
 df
    .map(row => test(row.getAs[String]("language")))
    .show
+--------+-----------+
|language|users_count|
+--------+-----------+
|    Java|        100|
|  Python|        100|
|   Scala|        100|
+--------+-----------+
```